# How to convert excel date long type to timestamp in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, timestamp, databricks

Column1 = 43784.2892847338

Tried this below option

```
val finalDF=df1.withColumn("Column1 ",expr("""(Column1 -25569) * 86400.0"""))
print(finalDF)
```

Result : 1911120001
Expected result should be in "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Could you please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `from_unixtime` then it will not give you the `.SSS` milliseconds. So, in this case, the casting is better to use.

```
val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1", 43784.2892847338))).toDF("id", "Column1")

val finalDF = df1.withColumn("Column1_timestamp", expr("""(Column1 -25569) * 86400.0""").cast("timestamp"))
finalDF.show(false)

+---+----------------+-----------------------+
|id |Column1         |Column1_timestamp      |
+---+----------------+-----------------------+
|1  |43784.2892847338|2019-11-15 06:56:34.201|
+---+----------------+-----------------------+
```